# Extending hair length in particle edit mode

Tags: particles, edit-mode, hair

Is there a way to extend hair in particle edit mode without expanding the entire strand of hair? The "length" tool in the brush menu makes the strand of hair longer, but it affects the entire strand. Here, I only need the end of the strand (the selected key) to extend outward. However, when I use the length tool, the entire strand of hair gets affected.
[image: Expanding hair]
This is what happens when I use the length tool

[image: Extending hair]

This is what I want to achieve.


Another question: My plan is to extend the hair at the very end and then subdivide it to get the necessary keys for editing. Will the entire hair get subdivided? Or will only the selected keys get subdivided?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Toolbar menu on Particle Edit Mode]

Uncheck the keep lengths on the toolbar menu for the comb tool. This will enable you to extend an individual key without affecting the others. As for the subdivision question, only the selected keys will be subdivided.