# Why is the hair clumping when I subdivide the particle?

Tags: particles, hair

After disabling "Keep Length" in particle edit mode and extending a key outward, the hair appears to be jagged and clumped together when I subdivide and start combing it. Is there a way to "reset" the children/particle so that the whole particle becomes... normal?
[image: Extending a key]
[image: Subdividing the keys]
[image: Jagged, clumped hair]
Here is the jagged, clumped hair problem^

Edit: Alright I added another image here to explain what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: You can change the size of particle using **cut** tool or **length** tool

Comment: yes, but using the length tool affects the entire particle, which I don't want because then I'll have to edit the whole thing. All I need is to extend the particle from the very end https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105272/extending-hair-length-in-particle-edit-mode/105275#105275

Comment: Maybe, you should increase hair resolution?

Comment: what do you mean by "resolution"? If that is the steps, that doesn't work as well